# Why is Twilio and Firebase not working cohesively using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, heroku, twilio

Why is twiml.message() working in one spot but is not working in the other?

I would like to read from firebase and send the results through SMS text using twiml/Twilio. Where the code is working and where it isn't is commented with an arrow.

The output should be: "Zoey was last seen (location) at (time)."

```
const accountSid = '**********************************';
const authToken = '*********************************;

// require the Twilio module and create a REST client
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var firebase = require('firebase');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var message = "N/A";

// setting the configurations for firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "***************************************",
  authDomain: "*************.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://**********.firebaseio.com",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.get('/reply', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
  console.log("sending: " + message);
  twiml.message(message);
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
  app.use(bodyParser());
  if(req.body.Body == 'Zoey') {
    // Send the message back with last known location.
    var body = 'Zoey was last seen in ';

    var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    databaseRef.once('value').then(function(snap) {
      // Get the location
      var lastLocation = snap.val().lastLocation;
      console.log("last location:" + lastLocation);
      body += lastLocation;

      body += ' at ';

      // Get the timestamp
      var timestamp = snap.val().timestamp;
      console.log("at " + timestamp);
      body += timestamp;
      console.log(body);
      message = body;
      twiml.message(body); //<---------------This doesn't work
    });
  } else {
    // Bad text message. Send the error message.
    var errorMessage = 'Please type Zoey and try again!';
    twiml.message(errorMessage);
  }
  twiml.message("This Works");//<----------------This Works!
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  res.end(twiml.toString());
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);

http.createServer(app).listen(1337, () => {
console.log('Server starting! Express server listening on port 1337');
});
```

Comment: What do mean by 'doesn't work'. Is it not being called? Is it being called but throwing an error? Is the `console.log(body);` right above the non-working call working?

Comment: It's not sending the body of the message with the lastLocation and timestamp when I text the Twilio number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok, my apologies.

Comment: Does this send "This Works" regardless of whether or not you send `Zoey`? Calling `twiml.message()` is probably just overriding previous calls with the last call to it before you response with twiml.toString().

Comment: I was helping her look at this earlier today. The message = body thing was when we were trying to set a global variable and then create a wait to see if we could force it to work. Basically the twiml.message works outside of the callback, but will not work inside the callback for firebase. We have had it commented out in each place, so it's not a one or the other thing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unable to test, but try this for the `app.post('/', ...` section

---

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {

    const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

    app.use(bodyParser());

    if (req.body.Body == 'Zoey') {
        // Send the message back with last known location.
        var body = 'Zoey was last seen in ';

        var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();

        databaseRef.once('value')
            .then(function (snap) {
                // Get the location
                var lastLocation = snap.val().lastLocation;
                body += lastLocation;
                body += ' at ';

                // Get the timestamp
                var timestamp = snap.val().timestamp;
                console.log("at " + timestamp);
                body += timestamp;

                return body;
            })
            .then(body => {
                twiml.message(body);
                res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
                res.end(twiml.toString());

            });

    } else {
        // Bad text message. Send the error message.
        var errorMessage = 'Please type Zoey and try again!';
        twiml.message(errorMessage);
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
        res.end(twiml.toString());

    }

}).listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

---

> ***Update: explanation***

If you look at your original code you have the `if/else` statement used to set the message for Twilio. After the if/else you have the code to send the response.

```
if (req.body.Body == 'Zoey') {
  // go to Firebase
  // use data from Firebase to include in message
  // it will take some time to receive the response from Firebase
  // somewhere in here set the message for Twilio

} else {
  // don't go anywhere
  // occurring at the same time
  // somewhere in here set the message for Twilio

}

// respond to Twilio  
// executed immediately 
// it does not wait for Firebase to respond
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
res.end(twiml.toString());
```

---

> **Sending the response to Twilio without waiting for Firebase to respond is a problem**, so..., let's look at the "Firebase section".

```
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
databaseRef.once('value')
.then(
    // execute a function when we get the response from Firebase
    // somewhere in here set the message for Twilio
);
```

What we could do is

```
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
databaseRef.once('value')
.then(
    // execute a function when we get the response from Firebase
    // return the message for Twilio
)
.then(
    // set the message for Twilio, using the argument 
    // passed by the return of the previous ".then()"
    // respond to Twilio
);
```

---

So, the code becomes:

```
if (req.body.Body == 'Zoey') {
    // go to Firebase
    // use data from Firebase to include in message

    var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    databaseRef.once('value')
        .then(function (snap) {
            // execute code when we get the response from Firebase

            // return the message for Twilio
            // "theMessage" will be passed to the next ".then()"
            return theMessage;
        })
        .then(function (theArgument) {
            // execute code when we get the return from the previous ".then()"
            // set the message for Twilio, using the argument 
            twiml.message(theArgument);

            // respond to Twilio
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
            res.end(twiml.toString());
        });

} else {
    // don't go anywhere, set the message for Twilio
    twiml.message("Please type Zoey and try again!");

    // respond to Twilio  
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
    res.end(twiml.toString());

}
```

> I'm sure this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) explains promises better than me.

---

***Note:*** You can get rid of the second `.then()` if you move the `// respond to Twilio` code up, at the end of the first `.then()`.